# Parse error- base64 image data in java

Tags: java, base64

I am reading xml data which has Base64 image data while Writing to a file getting "Error while parsing" error

Stacky's can you please help out with solution.Thanks waiting for earliest reply.

Below is Base64 image data sample tag & code to write to file.

```
<canididateimage>data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb
.......................................................                             </canididateimage>
```

Code to read Xml Base64 data:

```
String xmlData = request.getHeader("xmlData");
FileWriter fReader= new FileWriter(FileName);
fReader.write(xmlData);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting Error while parsing"? Which line? What's the *exact* stack trace? Are you sure this is really in a header?

Comment: Exact error is Error parsing HTTP request header.

Yes I am using Firefox Poster tool to test and adding xmlData into headers and posting.

Comment: Okay, well it sounds like it's not a valid header then... why are you specifying a *tag* as a *header*?

Comment: Hi Jon, the data is in format of structured xml. so tag is required along with Base64 image value

Comment: There's no need for it to be like that as an HTTP header though. It's *really, really odd* for an HTTP header to be in an XML tag. Why isn't this in the body instead?